# QuickBlox QBContent lifetime or autodeleting

Tags: ios, quickblox

can you help me with upload file on quickblox. I'm doing it like

```
[QBContent TUploadFile:data
                fileName:@"Image"
               contentType:@"image/png"
              isPublic:YES
              delegate:self];
```

But if i send id to other user. He can't delete file. I think file can be deleted only creator? How can I make deleting file on other side? Or can I just say to file to delete for example after 3 minutes? Because I can't do this with QBCBlob :(

Could some one help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content File can delete only its owner, you're right.

Why you need to delete it? It's not necessary to delete files.

If you need to delete files - you can use CustomObjects module for this http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-ios#Files

Custom Objects has Permissions API http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-ios#Permissions , so you can set proper permissions and delete record by any user

Comment: I think because QB give me a limit space for storing content. And I need to send file to other user and delete it

Comment: 10 GB it's too much space. 
You can delete old files each week/month through Admin panel

Comment: OK! Thanks. Tell me please, is there ability to sort by creating date?  Because I can't find in admin panel this filter. And can I download file from admin panel?

Comment: You can sort by ID, it's the same as by creating date. Do you use only images?

Comment: Yes. I just send image to other user. And don't want wait for response for delete on creator side

Comment: Yes, you can download images in Admin panel, just open image, right click - Save